Exception assertion causing failure
I have this ArgumentParser class:
from argparse import ArgumentParser

class ArgumentHandler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = ArgumentParser()
        self.parser.add_argument('--environment', help='Environment', choices=['TEST', 'DEV', 'PROD'], nargs=1, type=str.upper)
        self.parser.add_argument('--asofdate', help='As of date', nargs=1)

    def parse(self):
        parsed = {}

        args = dict(vars(self.parser.parse_args()))
        ...

        return parsed

I'm trying to test it using unittest:
def test_providing_incorrect_environment(self):
        print(f"RUNNING TEST CASE {inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name}")

        app = sys.argv[0] if len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[0] is not None else __file__
        sys.argv = [app, '--environment=UAT' ]

        with self.assertRaises(ArgumentError):
            ArgumentHandler().parse()

But I'm getting this error:
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --environment: invalid choice: 'UAT' (choose from 'TEST', 'DEV', 'PROD')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 593, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\unittest\case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "c:\ParisNmdProcessor\tests\components\helpers\test_argument_handler.py", line 57, in test_providing_incorrect_environment
    ArgumentHandler().parse()
  File "c:\ParisNmdProcessor\src\components\helpers\argument_handler.py", line 28, in parse
    args = dict(vars(self.parser.parse_args()))
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\argparse.py", line 1818, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\argparse.py", line 1854, in parse_known_args
    self.error(str(err))
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\argparse.py", line 2575, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
  File "C:\SWDTOOLS\PYTHON39\lib\argparse.py", line 2562, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2

What could be the cause? And how can I fix that?

"What could be the cause?" - read the traceback. ArgumentHandler().parse() doesn't raise an ArgumentError, it raises a SystemExit. Also note you should stop writing classes.

I do wish, though, that parse_args raised a "regular" exception, and provided another convenience wrapper that would exit the program on an error.

I think exit_on_error will redirect this kind of error.

@hpaulj You have to call parse_known_args explicitly for that to be useful; parse_args itself aborts unconditionally if parse_known_args returns any unconsumed arguments.

Using a debugger would probably have been the fastest. Apart from that, also for questions here, you need a [mcve], which often helps resolve issues like this, too.

@chepner, in this example the bad choice is processed right away (as exit or ArgumentError), before it tests for unrecognized or required arguments.  But the limitations of the exit_on_error option are known to the developers.  In any case unit-testing of argparse is tricky task.

You probably don't want to use nargs=1 - with that the values will be lists (with one string).  Also you don't need a dict()  around vars.  vars is already a dict.

Although the parser raises ArgumentError if there is an error while it is being configured, by default it will exit the program completely if there is an error while parsing. This is what is wanted in the most common use case: If the user enters a bad value, a help is displayed and the program is exited without you the programmer needing to do anything. See Invalid arguments in the documentation.
A program can override this behavior and handle errors manually by setting exit_on_error:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)

But in your case, since you are testing the code, you should just assertRaises(SystemExit) instead.
